# Project element at ordinal position

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongo-shell

I have a query that returns documents where the first element is equal to a string.

Example document:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "personal" : {
        "gender" : "Male",
        "given_names" : [ 
            "Trent", 
            "Paul"
        ],
        "surname" : "James",
        "date_of_birth" : ISODate("1984-04-28T23:00:00.000Z")
    },
    enrollments: [{
        "start_date" : ISODate("2003-01-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "name" : "Psychology",
        "school" : "Humanities",
        "score" : 27
    }] 
}
```

Query:

```
db.students.find({
    'personal.given_names.0': 'Trent'
})
```

I'd like to project only that first element.  I've tried using `$slice`:

```
db.students.find({
    'personal.given_names.0': 'Trent'
}, {
    'personal.given_names': {
        $slice: 1
    }
})
```

This does limit the array to the first, but projects everything else.  I also tried passing both `1` and the `$slice` operator to the projection but if seems that the `1` always overrides the `$slice` (regardless of ordering).

```
'personal.given_names': [1, { $slice: 1 }]
'personal.given_names': [ { $slice: 1 }, 1 ]
```

I've also tried referring to the ordinal position directly:

```
'personal.given_names.0': 1
```

How can I output *only* the first element of an array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.students.find({ 
    'personal.given_names': 'Trent'
}, {
    'personal.given_names.$': 1
})//removed ".0" from find
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this is only possible if you're projecting a single ordinal array position?  i.e. I couldn't project `1` and `2`?

Comment: $ sign stands for 0 th position of array ,if you want to project 1 and 2 position then you couldn't do it

Answer (score 0):

Using the aggregation framework you could do this:

```
db.students.aggregate({
    $match: { 'personal.given_names.0': 'Trent' } // find matching documents only
}, {
    $project: {
        '_id': 0, // remove "_id" field from output (and kind of everything else)
        'nameInArray': { $slice: [ '$personal.given_names', 1 ] }, // return only the first element of the array but still as an array
        'nameOnly': { $arrayElemAt: [ '$personal.given_names', 0 ] }// return only the first element of the array
    }
})
```